# Hide a div after first time visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage

I have a button (B) shows a menu (C) when clicking and a pop up (A) also shows the same menu (C) when clicking.
There are 4 things I need to do here.

**1) When clicking B, C appears. 

2) When clicking A, C appears.

3) When clicking B, A becomes hidden

4) A becomes hidden after first time visit. (like a welcome message)**

However, it doesn't seem to work if I add the script for the first time visit(I am using localStorage here). Could anyone know where went wrong?
Also, I am new to javascript so I am just looking for codes online and adding them to see if they work. I am not sure if there's any way to make the codes better?(now they are all separated.) Thank you.

Here is my code

```
<div class="user-menu-group">
    <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="hide('1sttime')" class="open-user-menu">B 
        <div class="notification" id="1sttime">
        <p>A</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="user-menu-bs">C</div>
</div>
```

here is my script

```
          <!--first time message-->
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              if (localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') !== undefined) {
                  $("#1sttime").hide();
              } else {
                  localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
                  $("#1sttime").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
              }
          });
          </script>

          <!--hide A after clicking B-->
          <script>
          function show(target) {
              document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
          }

          function hide(target) {
              document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
          }
          </script>

          <!--hide A after clicking it-->
          <script>
          (function () {
              var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('notification');
              for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                      this.style.display = 'none';
                  });
              }
          })();
          </script>
```

Comment: Why the mix of jQuery and plain JS?

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry, not sure how to do it with only JS. Especially the first time visit part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can have a single click handler for A and B, hide A and show C after click.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.open-user-menu, .notification').click(function(){
    $('.notification').hide();
    $('.user-menu-bs').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-menu-group">
    <a href="javascript:void()" onclick="hide('1sttime')" class="open-user-menu">B 
        <div class="notification" id="1sttime">
        <p>A</p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="user-menu-bs" style="display:none">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! However, the first time visit part still doesn't work. But I combined the two with your help. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help you :) As per your requirement, when user clicks on A or B, A gets hidden and there is no chance to click A again. Hence I kept single click handler where A gets hidden and C gets visible. Let me know I got the requirement wrong.